# How to calculate the times to generate number for "generate number from 0 to 1 until it is greater than X (e.g.:0.75)" in average?

Tags: probability

for example, I'm trying to test the average count for generate a number from 0 to 1 which is greater than X, let says 0.75, the program that I use (in javascript) to test it 100000 times:

`let avgCount=0;
for(let i=0;i<100000;i++){
  let count=0;
  while(Math.random()<0.75){
    count++;
  }
  avgCount+=count;
}
document.write(avgCount/100000);`

I found it roughly needs to generate 3 numbers until it becomes greater than 0.75.

And I found if X is 0.25, it becomes roughly 0.33 (I guess it is 1/3)

the relationship between X and avgCount (average count) I guess by editing the value of X is:

```
0.25 --- 1/3
0.5 --- 1
0.75 ---3
0.875 --- 7
->1 --- ->infinity
```

My question is, how to find the relationship between X and avgCount without programming testing (e.g.:by formula)? And what is the principle of the formula, if any?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of *succeeding* in each attempt is $p=1-x$.

The number of tries until a success follows a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) whose mean is $1/p$ -- but that nice formula also counts the final attempt that succeeds, whereas your program doesn't.

Correcting for this, we get that what your program *ought to* find is the relation
$$ x \quad\mapsto\quad \frac{1}{1-x} - 1 = \frac{x}{1-x} $$
which agrees exactly with your observations/guesses.